# jQuery/Javascript image gallery change image if hovered over for X but not if less than X

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, delay, image-gallery

There might be a really simple answer for this but I've been pondering it for a while and can't think what it is.

I have an image gallery with thumbnails and one main image, I'd like to change the main image if the user hovers over a thumbnail for say `500ms` but if they drag their mouse across the other thumbnails the time hovered would be less than `500ms` so I don't want the image to change.

Thanks to everyone that answered, just figured it out and came back to post it but you'd all beat me to it, thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you would have to use javascript timers with [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) and [clearTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout).

Basically you will create a timer when mouse enters you image - when the cursor goes out you clear it: if it hasn't run already, it xwill be cancelled.

```
var timer;
$('img').mouseenter(function() {
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        // do something here
    }, 500);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/Yx8Z5/)**

Comment: I had just figured it out and was going to post this :P Thanks for the time anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Try this ...

```
var timeout;
$('.yourimages').mouseenter(function() {
    timeout = setTimeout(function() { // remember the "task" id so we can clear it if required
        //change image
    }, 500); // number of milliseconds to wait
}).mouseleave(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout); // clear the timeout
});
```

It sets up a timer that executes after 500ms but resets if the mouse leaves the image. Obviously you need to replace the `.yourimages` with the class of the images and you could change the timeout if required

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mechanism like this:

```
var myTimer;
$('#myElement').hover(function(){
setTimeout(function(){
alert('Now I\'d be ready');
},500);
},function(){
clearTimeout(myTimer);
});
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout for info on `setTimeout()`

Another thing to add might be pointing you at the `hoverIntent`plugin, which might be just what you are looking for: http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html